# Error in using IF statement

Tags: arduino-uno

I am new to Arduino. Currently I am working on a project that used phone gyro sensor to control the movement of RC car.This is my code so far;

```
char blueToothVal;           //value sent over via bluetooth
char lastValue;              //stores last state of device (on/off)
String str,x,y,z;
int value = 0;


void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600); 

}


void loop()
{
if(Serial.available() >0 && value == 0 ) {
 str= Serial.readStringUntil('A');
 value = 1;

if(value == 1){
  x= Serial.readStringUntil(';');
  Serial.print("x = ");
  Serial.print(x.toFloat());
  Serial.print(" ");
  y=Serial.readStringUntil(';');
  Serial.print("y = ");
  Serial.print(y.toFloat());
  Serial.print(" ");
  z= Serial.readStringUntil('A');
  Serial.print("z = ");
  Serial.print(z.toFloat());
  Serial.println('\n');
  value = 0;
  delay(10);
 }
 }
if( y >=5 ){ //car forward
//CODING MOTOR HERE
}

if( y <= -3){ //car backward
//CODING MOTOR HERE
}

if( y >=5 && z >= 5){ //car steer to the left 
//CODING MOTOR HERE
}

if( y >=5 && z <= -10){ //car steer to the right
//CODING MOTOR HERE
}

if( y <= -3 && z >=5){ //car reverse to the left
//CODING MOTOR HERE
}

if( y <= -3 && z <= -10){ //car reverse to the right
//CODING MOTOR HERE
}

if( x >= 330.00){ // only left tyre go forward
//CODING MOTOR HERE
}

if( x <= 300.00){ // only right tyre go forward
//CODING MOTOR HERE
}
}
```

I am using Arduino Uno R3 and DF robot motor shield. My problem here is that this coding cannot be compile. Can someone shed me some light on where is my mistake and what should I do??

The error message:

> error: converting to 'const String' from initializer list would use explicit constructor 'String::String(int, unsigned char)'

indicating the line

```
if ( y >= 5 ){ //car forward
```

Comment: Yes the error state below like@Ben's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Compilation messages should be helpful.

First of them is:

> sketch_may17a:37: error: converting to 'const String' from initializer list would use explicit constructor 'String::String(int, unsigned char)'

The reason is y is a String and you do with it numeric comparaisons (for example):

```
if( y >=5 )
```

Replace it by:

```
    if( y.toInt() >= 5 )
```

Comment: Yea I thought I can do like that. Do u have any idea on what should I change?

Comment: @ZikriIrfan: you have to do a conversion from string to int: you can use .toInt() https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToInt => for example y.toInt()

Comment: Thanks @Benoît.Since my data in decimal form, I should replace it by if(y.toFloat() >= 5) right?